# Probability Density Function of a function of a continuous RV

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a continuous RV with density function
$f_{X}(x)\begin{cases} 
      \frac{2}{9}x,& x\in [0,1] \\
      0, &x \notin [0,1]  
   \end{cases}$

Let $Y=X(X-3)$. Determine the density of $Y$.

I am a bit with this problem especially given how $Y$ is defined and was wondering if someone could help me out. If you start by completing the square, i.e., $Y=(X-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{9}{4}$ would it take you anywhere? I have been trying with no result.

Attempt:

Let $g(X)=Y$. Then there is a theorem that states: If $X$ is a RV of the continuous type with PDF $f$, $y=g(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$ and strictly monotone, then $Y=g(X)$ is also a RV of the continuous type with PDF given by
$f_{Y}(y)\begin{cases} 
      f_{x}[g^{-1}(y)]|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|, &\alpha \lt y \lt \beta \\
      0, & otherwise 
   \end{cases}$

where $\alpha=min\{g(-\infty),g(+\infty)\}$ and $\beta=\{g(-\infty),g(+\infty)\}$

$g(X)=Y=X(X-3)=(X^2-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{9}{4}$ is differentiable and invertible so it satisfies the conditions of the thm above. Therefore
$Y=g(X)$ is also a RV of the continuous type with PDF given by
$f_{Y}(y)\begin{cases} 
      f_{x}[(y+\frac{9}{4})^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{3}{2}]|\frac{1}{2}(y+\frac{9}{4})^{-\frac{1}{2}}|, & y \in  [-2,0]\\
      0, & otherwise 
   \end{cases}$

 
And then just fill out the details ...

Comment: Maybe there is an error and the density is $k \, f_X(x)$? Because right now $\int_0^1 f_X(x) dx\neq 1$.

Comment: @Miguel You are right but I did not copy the question down wrong....Its an old quiz problem, maybe the Pr. changed it in class when it was handed out

Comment: Ok, but there is no way you can obtain a correct answer for a wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F_Y(y)=\mathbb P ( Y<y) = \mathbb P ( X(X-3)<y) = \mathbb P ( X^2-3X-y<0)$

Solve the polynomial equation $X^2-3X-y = 0$. If the roots are reals and distinct, then the polynomial expression is negative between the roots because the quadratic term is positive. Otherwise the probability is 0 and F_Y(y) = f_Y(y) = 0.

The roots are $x_+(y) = \frac{3+\sqrt{9+4y}}{2}$ and  $x_-(y) = \frac{3-\sqrt{9+4y}}{2}$.

$9+4y>0 \iff y>-\frac 94$

Therefore

$\forall y>-\frac 94, \ \mathbb P ( X^2-3X-y<0) = \mathbb P ( x_-<X<x_+) = F_X(x_+(y))-F_X(x_-(y))$

$f_Y(y) = x_+'(y) f_X(x_+(y))-x_-'(y)f_X(x_-(y))  $

$\forall y<-\frac 94, \ f_y(y)=0$

After this point you just need to finish the computation. But there is an error in your density equation so I will save it for later.

Comment: Thanks. But would the way I was thinking of doing it, completing the square work? $Y$ is defined on $[0,1]$, its support is $[-2,0]$ so find the inverse, chain rule...?

Comment: Yea you are are right. It is actually possible to apply the chain rule because your function is invertible in [0,1]. To apply the chain rule you just need to find the inverse of f(x) = x(x-3) which you can do easily with the nice form you found

Comment: @funmath Completing the square is just a way to obtain the formula for the second degree equation without learning it by heart :)

Comment: @Miguel Could you expand a bit? I am trying to reconcile what Max did and what I did (see attempt above). Since we just saw the theorem mentioned above in class and the function given was differentiable and invertible I was trying to do a direct application of the theorem, hence the thought of first completing the square. You are saying that what Max did is the "do from scratch approach, rather than apply a theorem approach" ? If there are any intuitive explanations that you can think of it would be really appreciated